# PHP upload script stopping/not returning after a while

Tags: wordpress, php

I have built a PHP script for uploading data from Excel (~40KB size) into DB sent via an Ajax request. It will insert 200 events, 500 registrations (Registrations for the events calendar pro plugin), insert around 500 users and pages and create 1000 PDFs.

It will insert/create this one by one (first events, then registrations etc.) and when I upload a smaller batch, the entire script works just fine. I can hereby upload the entire data, just in smaller pieces.

However, when I upload the entire data, it will always stop at the 3rd step (the insert of the users) and it will always do it at around 200 users without returning anything anymore - In the Console - Network Inspector it is still running.

I have increased the PHP settings to very high, but the error still exists:

```
memory_limit = 8216M
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600
post_max_size = 1028M
upload_max_filesize = 1028M
```

Can there be any setting either in PHP, Server or Wordpress that can cause this issue? I am just lost now after sitting on this now for a couple of days, if anyone has a hint or idea, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Whats your code?

Comment: I guess you have just bad design. You need to detach upload action from other actions like *"It will insert 200 events, 500 registrations"*. If you have everything together - that is the mess and impossible to debug and monitor. You have this long response not because of file upload, but waiting all those heavy inserts get done.

Comment: Did you look at your PHP Error log yet to see the error message produced when it stops running?

Comment: **and create 1000 PDFs** are you kidding me? :-) Same action? this kind of jobs should be done I would say like a cron job, but not ajax simple request :-)

Comment: the log says: Premature end of script headers: index.php. Is it really impossible to get it done via ajax ... that would mean I need to re-organize so much :(

Comment: Sounds like a timeout on the php script then. As the other guys mentioned, trying to get all that done in one script is unlikely to succeed.

Comment: what a pitty. Thanks all for the direction ...

Comment: Is it ok if I was to return the ajax call after each insert-step and then start a new one or do I have to create multiple upload buttons for each insert-step?

Comment: The problem is that is a huge payload for Ajax, PHP have his own limits, but make that process on ajax is a bad idea, my advice is recode your code, maybe with Jobs or queues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all the commentors are stating, the tasks you are trying to complete feel a bit much for an ajax call.

I'm guessing you regularly update the Excel file and need to update it to WP?

> Is it ok if I was to return the ajax call after each insert-step and
>   then start a new one.

Sure that's an option, i've build many ajax batch loaders for collecting large data sets and sending mail. This way you also circumvent PHP script timeouts.

Comment: I went for this solution to circumvent PHP script timeouts